# Replace (fill) values where the previous value is greater

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an unsorted array of integers, and I want to fill all decreasing numbers with the previous larger value.

Example:

```
>>> np.array([10, -1, 2, 5, 19, 5, 5, 4, 10, 2])
[10 10 10 10 19 19 19 19 19 19]

>>> np.array([0, 3, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2]
[0 3 5 5 5 7 7]
```

I've come up with this solution, but it has to be a more elegant way of doing it.

```
def func(a):
    a = a.copy()
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        if a[i] < a[i-1]:
            a[i] = a[i-1]

    return a
```

Any suggestions?

I have looked at two similar questions, but I am unable to modify the examples to make them work the way I intend.

1. [If value is greater than the previous replace with previous in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221610/if-value-is-greater-than-the-previous-replace-with-previous-in-pandas)
2. [Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.maximum.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
np.maximum.accumulate([10, -1, 2, 5, 19, 5, 5, 4, 10, 2])
# array([10, 10, 10, 10, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19])

np.maximum.accumulate([0, 3, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2])
# array([0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7])
```

Comment: Of course it had to be this simple... thanks, man!